# Enable to submit a form after a post() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have a tricky problem since 1 week...

On a page I have a simple form like this:

```
<form action="another-page.php" method="post" target="_blank" id="buyCredit">
    <button id="sendPayment">Access to this page</button>
</form>
```

On click on the button (witch has the id `sendPayment`), I have this code:

```
$('#sendPayment').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(buyCredit()).done(function(r_buyCredit){
        var json = $(r_buyCredit);
        if(json.type=="success") {
            alert('Success');
            $('form#buyCredit').submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('Error');
            alert(json.mess);
        }
    });

    function buyCredit() {
        $("#loader").toggleClass("hide show");
        return $.post("/assets/php/ajax/dashboard_buyCredit.php", "json");
    }
});
```

## Problem I have:

1. I can see with my dev tools, the ajax requests. They are good.
2. I can see my `alert('Success')`. So it entered in the `if()`.

**BUT** one thing do not work: **the form is not submitted**.
Like if it was blocked by another thing...

## The strange thing is..

If I remove this line, it's works.

```
return $.post("/assets/php/ajax/dashboard_buyCredit.php", "json");
```

Hopping you will help me!

Here a test link of this page:
http://goo.gl/Jn4o6y

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function `buyCredit()`. It's also not good practice to name functions like element IDs. Also...

- you seem to want to send your data via Ajax and not via traditional form transmit (i.e. one that reloads the page). But your POST call does not transmit any data. You can use `.serialize()` to turn the form into a string that you can post.
- You should listen to the `submit` event on the form instead of the `click` event on the submit button. There are other ways of submitting a form (like pressing Enter). You want to catch them as well.
- Using `event.preventDefault()` in the submit event handler prevents the traditional form transmit.
- jQuery decodes the response for you. You can use it directly, wrapping it in `$()` isn't useful.
- You can use the `.always()` callback of the Ajax call to switch off the loading animation reliably.

Modified code:

```
$('form#buyCredit').submit(function(event) {
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();

    event.preventDefault();

    $("#loader").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

    $.post("/assets/php/ajax/dashboard_buyCredit.php", formdata)
    .done(function (result){
        if (result.type === "success") {
            console.log('Success');
        } else {
            console.log('Error', result.mess);
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, status, statustext) {
        // an HTTP error has occurred, react to it 
    })
    .always(function () {
        $("#loader").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a `Error` in the console log. Result is : `{"mess":"Success","type":"success","token":"10||133414229958579507"}`. But the `result.type` do not work. Any help? We are near...

Comment: @poipoi What's the data type of `result`, when you look at it in your browser's developer tools? Set a breakpoint and inspect it the variable.